# Nested Hypervisor Installation - Xenserver in Vmware

Tags: vmware-vsphere, xenserver, hypervisor

I need to do some testing with Citrix Xenserver 7.x (not any guest VMs within it - the hypervisor itself) and want to run it as a Vmware 5.5 guest.  I have seen others who have successfully nested this way but I have failed to get it to work at this point.  The VM boots and the Xenserver installation process starts but very quickly reboots.  Here is a [screenshot of Citrix Xenserver 7.0 installation before rebooting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQCzT.png)

I saw one post stating

> enable: Expose hardware assisted virtualization to the guest OS

but I don't know how/where to do that.  I looked through the settings (via vSphere) of the VM and couldn't find any along those lines.

Another specified adding `vhv.enable = "TRUE"` to the VM's .vmx.  I haven't tried this yet.  Yet another page specified adding they same option and value but to the host's `/etc/vmware/config`, not the VM's .vmx.

Lastly, I found a page stating to add `featMask.vm.hv.capable = Min:1` and `virtualHW.productCompatibility = esx` (original value was `hosted`).  These changes did not help.

Also, it seems to maybe matter what the host's processors are.  Don't know - I'll have to get that info.

I am not a virtualization guy so I'm really just blindly throwing darts.  Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-8970

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Looks like I won't be able to do it as my AMD Opteron 6168 processors, on the desired ESX host, don't support AMD Rapid Virtualization Indexing (RVI).  Bummer.